# Get all items from list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How do i get all items from list?
Here is my code,

```
function checkFreebookingdateTime() {

getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;
spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
web = parentContext.get_web();
list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(getListCalender);
context.load(list);

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>');
collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);

context.load(collListItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    var listDetails = oListItem.get_item('EventDate') + "  " + oListItem.get_item('EndDate');

    alert(listDetails.toString());

 }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I get this error,

> TypeError, Unable to set property collListItem or undefined or null
>   reference

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var collListItem;` on top of the function

Remove `this` prefix's inside the function.

You final code will be

```
var collListItem;
function checkFreebookingdateTime() {
    getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;
    spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
    web = parentContext.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(getListCalender);
    context.load(list);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>');
    collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var listDetails = oListItem.get_item('EventDate') + "  " + oListItem.get_item('EndDate');
        alert(listDetails.toString());
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Then i get Unable to get property 'onQuerySucceeded' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Remove prefix this before onQuerySuceeded

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

try to use simply

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;
var spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
webURL: parentContext_webAbsoluteUrl,
listName: getListCalender,
CAMLViewFields: "<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("ows_EventDate"));
  });
}
});
});
</script>
```